# Form and required email type for input

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email-validation

When I create a form with required input:

```
<form action="" id="FormMessage"  method="post" >
    <div style="max-width:700px;">
                    <input name="InputEmail" id="InputName" class="email" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Your email" required>
            <div style="padding-top:20px">
                <button id="BtMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

If it's not filled we get this Warning message:

[image]

Example when trying to click on Send button without having filled The Email: http://jsfiddle.net/c9b47j9j/

Is there any way to get this same message but if what has been filled is not an email ?

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped you and for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you need to change input `type="text"` to `type="email"`. Then it will autovalidate the field as **EMAIL**. But remember this is just HTML 5 validation.

If you want to use some more additional validation you need to use `JS` OR `jQuery` pulgins, or write it yourself.
Some jQuery form validation plugin links below::

- https://jqueryvalidation.org/
- http://www.formvalidator.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following. It will validate email by default. No need for code.

```
<input type='email' />
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of input type='text', use input type='email'. this will validate that the user has entered a valid email address.

this is now supported in all major browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#search=type%3Demail

another way of achieving this is applying a regex using the pattern attribute:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have written "required" in

```
<input name="InputEmail" id="InputName" class="email" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Your email" required>`
```

This is actually an HTML validation keyword in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE version 9+ and Edge.

If you want to validate empty field validation without this alert, remove the "required" keyword and use JavaScript code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You've used

`type='text'`
but you need to use this
`type='email'`